# date retreival  in android

Tags: android, date

In my application i have  2 field, 1 is date and another is recc(is an integer) in database table.

Now i will explain my requirement:

Consider suppose user enters today's date(26-07-2012) and recc as 10.It means that starting from today's date to that +10 date.I got that 10th date from today's date.But what i want is 10th day from today's date means it will surely go to next month also (26-07-2012----5-08-2012),but i have to know the count of date which falls in this particular month,(i.e)between 26-07-2012----5-08-2012 how many days it will fall within this month.I think i have explained my problem clearly,if not i am ready to give more explanation.Thanks in advance.

Date value:

```
 EditText date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.startdateexp);       
             String startdate=date.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by following way:
1. Get date from Database.

Now get day of month from the date by following method:

```
DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
    date = iso8601Format.parse(dateTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Parsing ISO8601 datetime failed", e);
    }
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int currentDay= cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

calculate Last day of month by:

```
    int lastDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Date class you can offset it by the number of days converted to milliseconds to create a new Date:

```
Date datePlusRecc = new Date(oldDate.getTime() + recc*86400000);  // 86400000 = 24*60*60*1000
```

Note that this is useable only when recc is relatively small (< about 20), because otherwise the multiplication will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the java.util.Date class combined with your date in milliseconds.

In a for loop add one day to the one version in milliseconds and convert it back to Date. Get the Month out of the Date Object and compare it with the current month. As soon as the month is a new one you have your total count of days in the current month.

```
Date currentDate = new Date(currentMillis);
long countingMillis = currentMillis;
int daysInSameMonth = 0;
while(true){
    daysInSameMonth++; // if the actual date schould not count move this line at the button of the while
    countingMillis += 1000*60*60*24;
    Date dt = new Date(countingMillis);
    if(currentDate.getMonth() != dt.getMonth())
         break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks RaphMclee..When i am using ur code it showing                                                                    currentMillis cannot resolved into a variable

Comment: Hi Kevin Adesara...When i am using the above code it showing currentMillis cannot resolved into a variable .What can i do for that..

Comment: Here you have to convert date you retrieve from database into millis which is currentMillis.

Comment: currentDate is nothing but the date of your record from database.

Comment: Thanks  Kevin Adesara..Actually i am not taking start date from database.From edittext i am getting.See my edited post.How can i convert into milliseconds..

Comment: @prakash.k use DatePicker instead of EditText to get date from user. It will be easy for you to pick date. User can make mistake in entering date in formate of your need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14445/discussion-between-kevin-adesara-and-prakash-k)